# How to ajax call a php file hosted on remote server and receive a response?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

We are trying to call from index.html on local, a simple PHP file hosted on webhost000 to receive a response. PHP file is:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo ($name);
}
?>
```

We would like to simply input a character on a textbox in html.index and receive the same character as response from the php. We are using an ajax call to do this in html file:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').keyup(function() {   
        var name = $('#name').val();        
        var request = $.ajax({
              url: "https://nedo93.000webhostapp.com/phpdemo.php",                
              method: "POST",
              data: { name : name },
              dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Request done: " + msg );
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
              alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });         
        });
    });         
    </script>
```

(The remaining html should not be important, it works perfectly, tested and retested)

If we try to debug this we can see that the file is found, the request is sent, but we can't receive a response: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYx9w.jpg)

If we use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idRCZ.jpg) browser function instead, we can send data and receive a response without a problem, don't know if this can help.

Thank you in advance if you can answer this question.

Comment: You realise you're making a request for every single keystroke right? That's a lot of Ajax calls to make.

Comment: Yes I know, it's just a demo we are trying to do, it's not important for our final purpouse which is totally different, the problem is that it's not working, not even with just a single keystroke.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you're getting a 200 response from the server. That there's no data is an issue but it does look like the server is responding to the request. I assume you've tried `echo "TEST"; die;` at the top of the file? Does that produce anything. What do you get if you try `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: If we simply call the php file on browser, we get the response, but if we try to call it using the ajax function in html, it will make the request but nothing in response...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. If you run the PHP script in your local and try to get data using AJAX on local, this will work. But your PHP script and AJAX code are on 2 different servers. So according to the security model of Browsers they don't allow.

Comment: Yes this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your PHP script is hosted on a different server and your AJAX call code is on local.

For AJAX to run, there is same-origin policy. Under this policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin (means both are on same domain). [Read more about same origin policy here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

The same-origin policy prevents some Ajax techniques from being used across domains, although the W3C has a draft of the XMLHttpRequest object that would enable this functionality. Methods exist to sidestep this security feature by using a special Cross Domain Communications channel embedded as an iframe within a page, or by the use of [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), websockets, cross-domain messaging  or  [cross-domain resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

So in short you will not be able to access the PHP request residing on a 000webhost server to be accessed using AJAX code on local.

Either you host the AJAX code on the same 000webhost domain as well or enable cross-domain resource sharing on 000webhost domain where your PHP code is running.

As far I know, 000webhost is a free server and doesn't supports these changes. So you will have to either get a better server or test this all in a local.

Also as you mentioned in your query, all HTTP requests like GET, POST, PUT works cross domain. But for AJAX, no its not so straight forward.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank, you. This seems to be our problem. In fact if I upload index.html on webhost000, it will work. 
The problem is that we are using a React application locally and we cannot upload this application on webhost, so we are forced to make a call to another server.
Is there no way to achieve something like this?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, we will take a look at that.

Comment: Yes @EdoardoBianchi this can still be achieved. The best way would be to you JSONP - I will suggest to read and go through en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP.
Using script tag you can retrieve this data from server (as javascript script tag is allowed to fetch data from different server) and then use javascript to interpret the data fetched under the script tag by parsing and using it.

Comment: Also @EdoardoBianchi, hope I have helped so can you please accept my answer on this. :) That would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Yes this definetely helped us, thank you again :)
I think I accepted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

your code should be....

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); //just used as info for your application
    echo json_encode($name); //encode to JSON object
}
?>
```

after that do JQuery validation for checking Json reply (specially for error).

Comment: He's specifically checking for HTML by using `dataType: "html"` in the request. You should only echo JSON if that's what you expect back.

Comment: so You are looking for a http status code to decide next step.  isn't it ?? @EdoardoBianchi